# Esconder arquivos do inspecionar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Andei pesquisando sobre como esconder arquivos CSS, JS, JQUERY do inspecionar, mas tudo que achei foi antigo ou que não me ajudou muito. Gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma de esconder essas pastas para que quando alguém tentar inspecionar ele não consiga ver meus arquivos de CSS OU JS.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não da para ocultar a pasta static/js, mas da para não mostrar a pasta src. é só criar um arquivo .env(na pasta principal do projeto) e colar isso:
GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false

salvar e fazer o build.

*valido pra applicações ReactJs

Answer (score -3):

Isso não dá pra fazer, pense o browser necessita saber aonde estão os seus arquivos para poder renderizar o seu site seja local ou no servidor.

Comment: Isto não fornece uma resposta à pergunta. Para criticar ou solicitar esclarecimento de um autor, deixe um comentário abaixo da publicação dele. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/234239)

Comment: Obrigado, pelo o aviso!